# When can I use Javik as a companion?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If you don't know what the ME3 DLC is about, you may get spoiled.

I did the `From Ashes` mission, and now I have a living Prothean as a potential squadmate. However, in the first mission after rescuing him, I wasn't able to select him, he was grayed out.

He did mention that I was lying with words (as he sensed I'm a little too nice to people) when I told him I'd do anything to stop the reapers.

Do I have to be a Renegade before I can use him? Or will he become available later?
Why can't I select him from the get-go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He will become available after you do a mission. Still thawing out, you see.